# Haskell Parsec woes

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am trying to learn Parsec and am trying to parse a simple email address. 
I tried the following code. My expected output is the entire email address as a string. But when I run the code, I only get ".com" Could somene please tell me whats going on?

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import Text.Parsec
import Control.Applicative hiding ((<|>))

email = many1 alphaNum
     *> char '@'
     *> many1 alphaNum
     *> string ".com"

emailstr = parse email "" "xxxx@yyy.com"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The type signature for `*>` says it returns the result from the *second* parser, and throws away the result from the *first* parser. Thus, `email` returns only the result from the final parser in the sequence.

What you probably want is something more like

```
email =
  stitch
    <$> many1 alphaNum
    <*> char '@'
    <*> many1 alphaNum
    <*> string ".com"
```

This runs the four parsers and passes the result of each as an argument to `stitch`. If you write a suitable implementation for `stitch`:

```
stitch a b c d = a ++ [b] ++ c ++ d
```

then you should get back your string.

Notice that at this point, you could also put the username and domain into separate fields of a data structure or something:

```
data Email = Email {username, domain :: String}

email =
  Email
    <$> many1 alphaNum
    <*  char '@'
    <*> ((++) <$> many1 alphaNum <*> string ".com")
```

Now your parser returns an `Email` structure rather than just a plain string. That might not be what you're after, but it demonstrates how to write a more sophisticated parser.

All of this is using the `Applicative` interface to Parsec, which is generally considered good style. The *other* way to use Parsec is the `Monad` interface:

```
email = do
  a <- many1 alphaNum
  b <- char '@'
  c <- many1 alphaNum
  d <- string ".com"
  return (a ++ [b] ++ c ++ d)
```

Comment: Is this the idiomatic way to accomplish said task? I will not be using the code in production anywhere. I am simply trying to learn parsec.

Comment: Both ways are idiomatic